# Creating input variables in VBA (really basic VBA)

Tags: vba

I'm currently working on a project to create a NPV function for excel (essentially, recreating the already built-in excel function)..my VBA experience limited (essentially 0)

My question is how do you setup the function so that it allows to you point and click on cells...for instance, if i type in the name of my function myNPV...excel would say myNPV(rate,value1,value2....) and you could enter the data in for such cells...obviously my code would have to reflect and use the value inputs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arbitrarily sized parameter `ParamArray args()` is what you are looking for. This passes into the function an array containing all subsequent arguments.

With a paramarray, you should properly cover the situation of a multiple cell range being passed in, like "A2:A5", rather than assuming it will be passed in as "A2,A3,A4,A5". They need different treatments. The below handles this.

Used e.g. like:

```
Public Function myNPV(rate, ParamArray cashflows()) As Variant
    Dim npv As Double
    Dim arg, ele
    Dim i As Long
    For Each arg In cashflows
        If TypeOf arg Is Range Or VarType(arg) > vbArray Then
            For Each ele In arg
                npv = npv + ele / (1 + rate) ^ i
                i = i + 1
            Next ele
        Else
            npv = npv + arg / (1 + rate) ^ i
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next arg
    myNPV = npv
End Function
```

This assumes cashflow at the beginning of each period. For cashflows at the end of each period either: 1) discount the answer back by (1+rate) or 2) adjust the function to start with i = 1 rather than i = 0.

Edit:

Examples (FYI Excel NPV assumes cashflows at end of period):

```
=myNPV(5%,-100,10,10,110) -> 13.62 (same as Excel NPV * 1.05)
=myNPV(5%,-100,10,10,110)/1.05 -> 12.97 (same as Excel NPV)
=myNPV(A1,B1:E5)
=myNPV(A1,B1:E5,G1:H20) etc
```